# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed - decryption issue

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to decrypt the content using following method

```
public string DecryptContent(string data)
{
    string decryptedContent = data;       
    try
    {
       byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(decryptedContent);
       using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
       {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_secretKey, 
                                         Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_secretSalt));

            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = 
                 new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                 }
    
                 decryptedContent = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        // {"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."}  <--- THROWS AN EXCEPTION
     }

     return decryptedContent;
}
```

I tried to add

```
encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
```

but this gives some weird Chinese like letters as the result of this method

Tried also with

```
 encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
```

but still getting an exception!

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not close the CryptoStream within using statement. Remove `cs.Close();`.

Comment: @pilippApe thanks, removed. Issue still exists

Comment: @PhilippApe how does that improve anything and how does that address the OP issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the padding mode explicitly?

Comment: as I said in the question I tried with  PaddingMode.Zeros

Comment: @zaggler the CryptoStream has to call FlushFinalBlock. `Close()` and `using` can call it twice then.
The remaining code seems to be okay though. I think there could be an issue with the encode part.

Comment: Are you sure about that Encoding.Unicode? Could be UTF-8 and because of that you get "Chinese" letters. Drop a note if this helps.

Comment: @WiktorZychla UTF-8 didn't help. With UTF8 I'm getting now 'Bv)RO�\u0003�U���,�f

Comment: That's unfortunate. But you're closer probably. Are you sure about these 32/16 now?